# how to start redis 3.2 using a dump.rdb generated by redis 2.8

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I created a dump.rdb using redis server version 2.8.22. It is ignored when redis server 3.2 is started. Is the data format in Redis 3.2 backward compatible with that in version 2.8.22?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not backward compatabile. I have tested the same and it works fine. The values in dump.rdb is stored in the folder you have your executable redis-server. So make sure you copy the file in 2.8.22 to 3.2. Otherwise values on dump.rdb inside 3.2 folder alone will be shown. Also make sure your redis server is not running during this process. Also make sure you start the redis server with `./redis-server redis.conf` command. Only in redis.conf you will have the path to your dump.rdb file, by default it will take the dump file in parallel to redis-server.